# Is it possible to find number of td's within table and then apply col width inside table tag by using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to add "`col width`" tag according to number of `td` tags, within Table tag. if there are 2 td's,then it should add 2 "`col width`". & if there are 3 then, 3 "`col width`". and so on.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>HTML colgroup Tag</title>
</head>

<body>
    <p>This example shows a colgroup that has three columns of different widths:
    </p>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Heading</th>
            <td>col 1</td>
            <td>col 2</td>
            <td>col 3</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>col 1</td>
            <td>col 2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Please can anyone help me,to add "`col group`" tag according to number of `td`.

Expected Output:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>HTML colgroup Tag</title>
</head>

<body>
    <p>This example shows a colgroup that has three columns of different widths:
    </p>
    <table border="1">
        <colgroup>
            <col width="50%"></col>
            <col width="20%"></col>
            <col width="30%"></col>

        </colgroup>
        <tr>
            <th>Heading</th>
            <td>col 1</td>
            <td>col 2</td>
            <td>col 3</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table border="1">
        <colgroup>
            <col width="50%"></col>
            <col width="50%"></col>

        </colgroup>
        <tr>
            <td>col 1</td>
            <td>col 2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes, JS can hack up the DOM pretty much any way you want.

Comment: Really, can you please send me any demo

Comment: Firstly, any reason you don't generate this HTML markup server side? BTW, what is the logic regarding `col` attribute `width` value? Why 50, 100, 200 & 50%?

Comment: Following your edit, now there is 4 cols for 3 tds, and you still don't answer questions... It sounds like you don't really know what to expect

Comment: oops I am sorry ,i will just modify it.

Comment: are you looking for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/erxwao9h/1/

Comment: Yeah Sushil

Its good but if i had one or more tables within Body,then its adding col width belw first table only.

instead of adding to its corresponding table

http://jsfiddle.net/erxwao9h/2/

Comment: you can do a each loop on the tables and append it in the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to first loop through the `tables` and get the `td` count for each table. and then create a `colgroup` based on the count of td's

something like this

```
var output = '';
$('table').each(function() {

    var colCount = 0;
    $(this).find('tr:nth-child(1) td').each(function() { // Get the count of table columns

        if ($(this).attr('colspan')) { // if there is a <td colspan>
            colCount += +$(this).attr('colspan');
        } else {
            colCount++;
        }
        console.log($(this));
    });


    var colgroupList = '';
    for (i = 0; i < colCount; i++) { // Add a <colgroup></colgroup> for each <td>
        colgroupList += '<col width="50%"></col>';
        console.log(colgroupList);
    }
    console.log('<colgroup>' + colgroupList + '</colgroup>');

    $(this).find("tbody").prepend('<colgroup>' + colgroupList + '</colgroup>');

    output += $(this).html();

});
```

here's a working **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/erxwao9h/3/)** for the same.

Comment: Really Yaar you are extremely outstanding.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you can count the number of tds in the table by:

```
var count = $('#tableId td').length();
```

You can add atrributes to a table by doing:

```
$('#tableId').attr('name', 'value');
```

Comment: Can you explain with fiddle please

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('table').each(function(){
    var t = jQuery(this);
    var count = t.children('tr').eq(0).find('td').length;
    var colgroup = jQuery('<colgroup/>', { 'span': count });
    for(var i = 1; i <= count; i++){
        colgroup.append('<col/>',{ 'width' : (100/count)+'%' };
    }
    t.prepend(colgroup);
});
```

Untested but should be a good starting point

Comment: Hey @jordon Davidson,Thanks for ur reply.

but its not appending col group tag as i need.

http://jsfiddle.net/yk6Tq/37/

Comment: Updated the code. in the fiddle. There were a few typos.

Note, the <th> in the first set throws the columns off, so you'll need to play with your markup and which row to count.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use jQuery to make things easy.

Here is an example (I used the id "table1" in the table):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var size = $("#table1 tr:first > td").length;
var tg = '<colgroup span="' + size + '">';
for(x=0; x<size; x++) {
    tg += '<col></col>';
}

tg += '</colgroup>';
$(tg).insertBefore('#table1 > tbody > tr:first');
```

});

Hope it helps.